# In MVC RadioButton , In the Model Should one use an int or a bool?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

Im my model, Is it best to use an int or a number of bools to store each RadioButtons state?

I see examples using int, id prefer to use a bool for each rdo button for ease of searching in Linq2Sql.

Whats the best practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A radio button group represents a **single property** that can have **one** of many values.

Therefore, `int` is a more logical choice than `bool`.

Perhaps a set of flags would better describe your model?  In that case, `[Flags] Enum` would be an excellent model.

Finally, if your data is stored as a set of `bool` values, then a group of checkboxes would make more sense.

Comment: Thanks Scott, that's helped a lot to clear it up in my mind. Great idea using Flags enum.